# ASP.NET AJAX JavaScript files served from a static location

Tags: asp.net, ajax, static, webforms

I realise that this is going to be a fairly niche requirement and will almost certainly raise a few "WTF's" but here goes...

Within an ASP.NET Webforms application I need to serve static content from a local client machine in order to reduce up-front bandwidth requirements as much as possible (Security policy has disabled all Browser caching). The idea is to serve CSS, images and JavaScript files from a location on the local file system referenced by filesystem links from within the Web application (Yes, I know, WTF's galore but that's how it is). The application itself will effectively be an Intranet app that's hosted externally from a client but restricted by IP range along with standard username/password security. So it's pretty much a hybrid Internet/Intranet application but we can easily roll out packages of files to client machines. I am **not** suggesting that we expect nor require public clients to download packages of files. We have control to an extent over the client machines in terms of the local filesystem and so on but we **cannot change the caching policy**.

We're using UpdatePanel controls to perform partial page updates which obviously means that we need to Microsoft AJAX JavaScript files. Presently these are being served (as standard) by a standard resource handler within IIS/ASP.NET. Ideally I would like to be able to take these JS files and reference them statically from a client machine, and no longer serve them via an AXD.

My questions are:

- Is this possible?

  If it is possible, how do we go about doing so?

In order to attempt to pre-empt some WTF's the requirement stems from attempting to service a requirement with as little time and effort as possible **whilst a more suitable solution is developed**. I'm aware that we can lighten the load, we can switch to jQuery AJAX updates, we can rewrite the front-end in MVC etc. but my question is related to what we can quickly deploy with our **existing** application architecture.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would be LOL but I've seen it too many times to laugh about it now. Your temporary solution will live longer than you think and hope. I swear the uglier the architecture, the longer people live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Lorna,

maybe your security team is going crazy. What is the difference between serving a dynamic HTML generated by the server and a dynamic JS generated by the server?

It does not make any sense. You should try talking them out of it.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. However it's not related to security at all, we have a requirement to reduce up-front load time for the application as much as possible. There is policy in place that the desktop machines do not cache Browser content. We've done some tests and by deploying the scripts in Release mode, and with IIS compression enabled we can get them down to about 40kb. However each site has a contended, very low bandwidth line. Quite literally every byte counts. I realise the irony since we're using UpdatePanels but despite Bernhard's misgivings this is a temporary solution.

Comment: Why you can´t cache stuff in the client? Maybe this policy can be removed "temporarly" while you develop a new version with jQuery or other JS frameworks. Still, this policy looks very odd and makes no sense. Update Panel != Performance. 

Tell us a little bit more about the environment where every byte counts. I´m very curious.

Comment: The organisation has disabled browser caching as a company-wide policy and will not re-enable it for this application. The application itself is (clearly) not designed for this environment, so the intention is to try and get something in place with local JS content whilst in the meantime we rewrite the front-end using jQuery or the MS AJAX Framework without the use of update panels. I completely understand that UpdatePanel != Performance, they're not going to change their caching policy unfortunately.

The environment is a distributed network of branches on very low speed, contended lines.

Comment: Apologies Tucaz, I've edited the question to more accurately reflect the situation. We don't have "complete control over the client machine configuration". I've amended it to reflect the fact that we have control over the local filesystem only.

Answer (score 0):

what is the average size of pages and viewstate data. you might need to store viewstate in sqlserver rather than sending it to client browser every time.

Comment: Many thanks for you response. 

ViewState is disabled and the average page size is very small, circa 5kb - 8kb or thereabouts. 

The real issue is the up-front load time for resources such as CSS and JS since they're not being cached.